# Regex to exclude substring

Tags: regex-negation

I want to write regex that:

1. pass string starting with `/scripts/my_app/` (`/scripts/my_app/xxxx.sh` or `/scripts/my_app/yyyyy/xxxz.sh`)
2. exclude another strings starting with `/scripts/` (`/scripts/another_string/xxxx.sh` or `/scripts/some_string/yyyyy/xxxz.sh`)
3. pass any others strings like `/xxxx/yyyy/zzzzz/qqqq.sh` or `/aaaa/bbbb/ccc.sh`

Something like this `^[(\/scripts\/my_app\/)|(?!\/scripts\/)].*` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^/(?:scripts/my_app/|(?!scripts/)).*
```

**Explanation**

- `^/`  Start of string and match `/`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `scripts/my_app/` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!scripts/)` Negative lookahead, assert not `scripts/`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `.*` Match 0+ times any character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUfC0O/1)

Another option is using a double negative lookahead

```
^/(?!scripts/(?!my_app/)).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ol2SVM/1)

Comment: Thank you! I don't know about (?: Non capture group

Comment: Second option don't work properly on string like /scripts/my_app_OLD/  Need to be added  slash  ^/(?!scripts/(?!my_app/)).*

Comment: @user3441194 Ah, it should be `^/(?!scripts/(?!my_app/)).*` https://regex101.com/r/ol2SVM/1